# Whats the point of על נקיות?

Tags: blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing

Kitzur 2:6 address how one should be scrupulous in netilyat yadayim. He concludes with a scenario where one has no water. It's advised to say 'AL nikiyut yadayim' and then when water is found wash but don't say another bracha. However, this "dry" wash doesn't remove the ruach ra.

So what's the point of wiping hands with a cloth? I thought the whole point of netilyat yadayim was to remove the ruach ra - with or without a bracha.

Comment: The purpose of netilat yadayyim is to have clean hands to prepare for prayer or eating.

Comment: Your question doesn't have many upvotes. Perhaps it needs work. A) Your question cites a text named "Kitzur". What is this work? Please [edit] your question and be more verbose. Try to add in either the full title of the work, or the name of its author. B) Your question's title is rather short; please lengthen it. C) Please check your entire question for typos and other things which imply a possible lack of copyediting.

Answer (score 1):

SA OC 4, 22:

> אם אין לו מים, יקנח ידיו בצרור או בעפר או בכל מידי דמנקי ויברך "על נקיות ידיים". ויועיל לתפילה, אבל לא להעביר רוח רעה שעליהן.‏
>
> A person who has no water ... and bless al nejiut yadayim, this is useful for praying but not to ckean the evil spirit.

One of the functions1
of washing hands in morning is to clean ES, if he did sleep, but one else function is to be the washing befor prayer, as there is for mincha and arvit prayer in which there is generally no ruach raa.

See also 233,  2.

There is an halacha to wash before praying, even if his hands are clean, even if he was learning Tora. If there is no water, he needs to clean his hands wipping with a rub (Baer Hetev sk 7). The MB sk 20 explains that this last rule is not sufficient if he kbow that his hands were soiled. See Bait Chadash 232 and 92 . There is a Gemara that says that for praying if there is no water, he needs to clean with sand.

For cleanliness needed for prayer, without water nekiut yadayim is usefull. But in morning only chazal  statued a blessing. The blessing is not because of the evil spirit only, e.g. if he rinse his hands in a cup,  this is not good for evil spirit but he blesses al netilat, see SA OC 4,   12 Magen Avraham sk 9.

Comment: "in morning only chazal statued a blessing" - is there a source in Hazal for not making the blessing when washing before Minhah or Arvit?

Comment: Yes see shut harashba, quoted in an other mine post, see SA OC 232

Comment: Do they quote a passage in Hazal?

Comment: see Mishna berura 233 sk 17. @paquda, for chazal I don't know yet.